How can I stop the texture from skewing when I move the camera?
I UV projected a floor on my ground plane and it looks great from most angles but when I move the camera (not the projection cam) to the far left the floor isn't reacting as it would in real life: with the lines aligning. Is there any way to fix this? Attaching a photo of the image I used to project and then what it looks like when I set up the moving camera (as you can see, everything is skewing right)


Does your floor object have enough vertices (for UV project) ? What you are experiencing is probably simply how UV project works. It looks good only near the original camera position

Hey and thanks for your reply @Lutzi If you mean subdivisions, I think I have enough> I just tried adding a bunch more but it didn't change anything. That's a bummer if this is just how it works. Do you know if baking the texture into the plane would make any difference? I'm not very familiar with baking materials/textures but if this will fix the problem I don't mind going down the youtube rabbit hole for some baking tutorials

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

@Jakemoyo Hi Jake, baking the image unto the floor seemed to work to get rid of some distortion, but also I realized that I was outside of the area that the camera angle was outside of the part of the plane that I had uv projected unto so the warped part was from the mirroring and extending effect, which I was able to rectify with changing the UVs. Thanks for your willingness to help though :)
